# how to set horizantally scrollable gridview in android

Tags: android, xml, gridview

I am trying to scroll a gridview but not able to do so. How can I scroll the grid view horizontally.

my xml has

```
  <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
        android:numColumns="10" >
    </GridView>
```

please anyone.

Answer (score 0):

The standard `GridView` scrolls only vertically.

Wrapping `GridView` that does its own scrolling in another scroll container such as `HorizontalScrollView` is a bad idea.

However, there are some third party libraries that allow you to configure the scroll direction of a grid view, e.g. [jess-anders/two-way-gridview](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview).

Comment: is there any other way like can I populate the data in a table dynamically ? so that it can scroll horizontally. Using table view or sumthing?

Comment: @RidaShahid I'm not sure what you're asking. The question was about scrolling a gridview horizontally - you need something like a 2d scrollable table?

Comment: I want to achieve this thing 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815115/settgin-string-in-gridview